# Why this while loop stops working suddenly

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm doing the classic happy number problem on C++ implementing a linked list, but this while loop stops working mid-way through and since I'm new on this language I can't spot why is that. Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "simplelists.h"
using namespace std;

int number() {
    int x;
    bool valid = false;
    do {
        cout << "Input the number to check if it's happy: ";
        cin >> x;
        if (cin.good() && x > 1) {
            valid = true;
        }
        else {   //to clear inputs
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "\nInvalid input" << endl;
        }
    } while (!valid);
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int x = number();
    int index;
    int n = 0;

    SimpleList* digits = new SimpleList();

    while(true) {
        index = x % 10;
        n += index * index;
        x /= 10;

        cout << "hi " << index << " " << n << " " << x << endl;

        if (n == 1) {
            cout << "The number is happy! :)";
            break;
        }
        else if (digits->search(n)->data != n) {
            cout << "The number isn't happy :(";
            break;
        }
        digits->InputAtEnd(n);
        x = n;

        cout << "hi " << x << " " << digits->search(n)->data << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically it's the while loop from main() that suddenly stops working. I'm actually printing
`cout << "hi " << index << " " << n << " " << x << endl;` and
`cout << "hi " << x << " " << digits->search(n)->data << endl;` to see what's happening, and the first line is only displayed once while the second one isn't displayed at all.

Comment: we need the header file to so we can test it out- simplelists.h

Comment: `SimpleList` is not a standard type in C++.  Presumably `digits->search(n)` or `digits->InputAtEnd()` are doing something that causes them not to return  (e.g. calling `exit()`, throwing an exception).    Also, there is no need for `digits` to be a pointer initialised with a `new` expression - that is a clear habit you have from some *other* programming language, and is unnecessary (and often undesirable) in C++.

Comment: @Peter thank you! I checked for what you said and indeed that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter commented, the problem was the line `else if (digits->search(n)->data != n)` because in my 'simplelists.h' class the search method returned NULL if it found no data, and since that's the case for the first iteration, the loop just stopped working.

To fix this, I changed that conditional to `else if (digits->search(n) != NULL)` .